# Use the event of a recyclerview in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Good morning friends, 
My problem is the following. I have a cardview with a button, i catch the button event in the recyclerview, but I would like to catch the button event in the fragment that contains the recyclerview.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {


    myViewHolder.imagen.setImageResource(mData.get(i).getImage());
    myViewHolder.title.setText(mData.get(i).getTitel());



    myViewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"ok"+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });



}
```

I need to use the event here.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_form4, container, false);





    list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new POJOcarviewFotoForm4(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp,"Picture"));
    list.add(new POJOcarviewFotoForm4(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp,"Picture"));
    list.add(new POJOcarviewFotoForm4(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp,"Picture"));
    list.add(new POJOcarviewFotoForm4(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp,"Picture"));
    list.add(new POJOcarviewFotoForm4(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp,"Picture"));


    RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.form4_recyclerview);
    RecyclerViewAdapterFotoForm4 adapterFotoForm4=new RecyclerViewAdapterFotoForm4(getContext(),list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterFotoForm4);




    return view;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a callback(interface) to communicate between adapter and fragment. For example consider following callback (you can have it as a separate file):

```
public interface OnClickCallback {
    void onClicked(int position);
}
```

In your fragment implement it so you will have following override method

```
@Override
public void onClicked(int position){
// you will be retriving the clicked position 
}
```

In your fragment create an instance OnClickCallback and pass it to adapter so that in on setOnClickListener method of adapter you can communicate with fragment using callback.

```
private OnClickCallback onClickCallback;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_form4, container, false);

    onClickCallback = this;



    list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new POJOcarviewFotoForm4(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp,"Picture"));
    list.add(new POJOcarviewFotoForm4(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp,"Picture"));
    list.add(new POJOcarviewFotoForm4(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp,"Picture"));
    list.add(new POJOcarviewFotoForm4(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp,"Picture"));
    list.add(new POJOcarviewFotoForm4(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp,"Picture"));


    RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.form4_recyclerview);
    RecyclerViewAdapterFotoForm4 adapterFotoForm4=new RecyclerViewAdapterFotoForm4(getContext(),list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterFotoForm4, onClickCallback);

    return view;
}
```

There in adapter constructor :

```
public Adapter(List<String> yourList, OnClickCallback itemClickCallback) {
        this.yourList = yourList;
        this.itemClickCallback = itemClickCallback;
    }
```

In setOnClickListener you can call it as follows :

```
myViewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           itemClickCallback.onClicked(position);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. could you tell me if I am doing wrong with the adapter?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. could you tell me if I am doing wrong with the adapter? here I have to implement the adapter. public class RecyclerViewAdapterFotoForm4 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterFotoForm4.MyViewHolder> {

    OnClickCallback itemClickCallback;
    Context context;
    List<POJOcarviewFotoForm4> mData;
    View view;

    public RecyclerViewAdapterFotoForm4(List<POJOcarviewFotoForm4> list, OnClickCallback itemClickCallback) {
        this.mData = list;
        this.itemClickCallback = itemClickCallback;
    }

Comment: I can not enter two parameters here      RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.form4_recyclerview);
        RecyclerViewAdapterFotoForm4 adapterFotoForm4=new RecyclerViewAdapterFotoForm4(getContext(),list);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterFotoForm4, onClickCallback);

Comment: Please refer this link for recycler view clear understanding : https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: Thanks for the help